# Xypic problem: can't find file

Tags: fonts, errors, xy-pic

I'm trying run pdflatex, but I get this one very unusual error. I've downloaded xypic from CTAN, and it still seems that pdflatex is unable to find some documents that are supposedly related to that package (I did texhash). Here's the output:

```
 Xy-pic version 3.8.4 <2010/10/11>
 Copyright (c) 1991-2010 by Kristoffer H. Rose <krisrose@tug.org>
 Xy-pic is free software: see the User's Guide for details.

Loading kernel: messages; fonts;
kpathsea: Running mktextfm xydash10
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input xydash10
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf xydash10
! I can't find file `xydash10'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input xydash10

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input xydash10

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: xydash10.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input xydash10' failed to make xydash10.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \xydashfont=xydash10 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \gdef 
l.159 \xydef@\xydashl@
                      {\fontdimen6\xydashfont}
?
```

Comment: What do you get if you do `kpsewhich xydash10.mf`?  Also, does `kpsewhich xy.sty` point to where you just downloaded `xypic` to?

Comment: (I expect Stefan's right; if so, ignore the above comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to enable the xy-pic font map file running `updmap-sys`:

```
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map xypic.map
```

If you installed LaTeX from the Debian repositories, you could install the LaTeX package bundle which contains xy-pic, it's `texlive-pictures`, see [package information](http://packages.debian.org/sid/texlive-pictures).

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-pictures
```

If you installed LaTeX using tlmgr, use tlmgr as well for the installation of xy-pic.

```
tlmgr -gui
```

or

```
tlmgr install xypic
```

Note, the package may be called xypic instead of xy-pic.

Comment: Installing texlive-pictures did the trick. Thanks a lot! I've pressed to accept the answer but I'm unsure if site did accept it..